# Ошибка Javascripts

Tags: jquery, javascript

http://ii.tj/  - когда в файле app.js который подключается я убераю вот эти строчки. то все кнопка в правом верхнем углу сайта войти или регистрация нормально работают, если же я вставляю этот код что ниже, то они не работают должным образом. Сейчас задокументировал эти строчки посмотрите пожалуйста... проблема точно в куске кода что ниже.. без него все работает....

```
 $('#user_login').parents('form').ajaxForm({
    if (responseText == "good") {
            location.href=location.href;
        }
        else {
            $("#ajax-messages").text(responseText);
            $.colorbox({href: "#vadal", inline: true, open: true});
            $("#vadal").find('.close').click(function(){ $.colorbox.close(); return false; });
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Лишняя фигурная скобка после return false;